# The most efficient way to break down huge file into chunks of max 10MBs

Tags: linux, algorithm, computer-science

There is a text file of a size of 20GBs. Each line of the file is a json object. The odd lines are the ones describing the even subsequent lines.

The goal is to divide the big file into chunks of maximum size of 10MBs knowing that each file should have even number of lines so the formatting doesn't get lost. What would be the most efficient way to do that?

My research so far made me lean towards:

1. split function in Linux. Is there any way to export always even number of lines based on the size?
2. Modified version of divide & conquer algo. Would this even work?
3. Estimating average number of lines that meet the 10MBs criteria and iterating through it  & exporting it it meets the criteria.

I'm thinking that 1. would be the most efficient but I wanted to get an opinion of experts here.

Comment: What are the typical and maximal numbers of bytes in even and odd lines?

Comment: Line breaks are for human-readability, so if you did find some program or function to split a file, be careful that it isn't chopping through the middle of a line.

Comment: @anatolyg not quite sure about that.

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks for the advice. Does the split command do it the right way?

Comment: You could find out by `man split` in your terminal

Comment: I would use a Python script that repeatedly reads line pairs and writes to a new file when 10 MB have been reached. The task is disk-bound, so CPU efficiency won't be an issue.

Comment: Maybe just combine line pairs into single lines, use split, then restore line pairs: `sed 'N;s/\n/+/'` `sed s/+/\\n/`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I like your approach the best so far. Any reason why Python and not other languages like node js or php?

Comment: @user1029829: I don't know about your background. With Python it would take myself like 10 minutes.